# Explanation of JavaFX Table View Cell Renderer?

Tags: javafx-8

I am very curious about an example that I am trying to imitate in my own code. My own code isn't working yet and I'm confident that it is because I don't understand the example very completely. Unfortunately, the person who prepared the example didn't bother to explain it in much detail either. I was wondering if someone could walk me through each of the three classes - especially the part in Main.java that involves setCellFactory() and setCellValueFactory() - line by line and explain what exactly is going on?

This is a link to the example:[JavaFX8 – Render a DatePicker Cell in a TableView](http://blog.physalix.com/javafx8-render-a-datepicker-cell-in-a-tableview/)

The code clearly works as it is; I've run it myself and satisfied myself that it works. I've run it in Debug mode of Eclipse also but don't really understand what I'm seeing. I was hoping someone could explain it line by line. With a bit of luck, that will "make the penny drop" so that I can see what I am doing wrong.

Or can someone suggest a better approach to understanding why the example works but my code doesn't?

Comment: Have you read through the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm)?  In broad terms - the `cellValueFactory` is what assigns a value from the row model to the specific cell, while a `cellFactory` is used to create a custom cell - usually to provide custom editing or custom (non-textual or custom-formatted) display.   As to why your code doesn't work - it is virtually impossible to tell without seeing it.

Comment: The example you linked is truly awful. I would start with something else. For a general overview, the [documentation for `Cell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) has a reasonable description of the lifecycle of a cell instance, particularly with respect to editing.

Comment: sillyfly - I've gone through the Oracle tutorial and I get the *basic* idea of what the CellFactory and CellValueFactory is but I need a more advanced sense of what is going on, especially in the example I've cited. The *only* example I've found of using a DatePicker to choose/display/change a date in a tableColumn is the one I've cited but it isn't awfully helpful in understanding everything that is going on. I'm reluctant to put my own code here since it's going to be a biggish job to concoct a version that shows enough to demonstrate the problem while stripping out everything else.

Comment: sillyfly - But I *will* put my own code up there is that's the best way forward; obviously, you can't troubleshoot code you can't see :-)

Comment: James_D - So it's not just me that thought the example left a lot to be desired? Well, that's good to hear. I was afraid I might be asking too much :-) I'll have a look at the Cell documentation and see if that is enough to get me over the hump. But I'm afraid I *really* don't understand the way the setCellFactory is executed. Why the Callback and all that goes with it? (Maybe I need to review Callbacks in general but even then I'm not sure why Callbacks are necessary *here* in particular.)

Comment: I don't know who created this example, but (s)he does not even know the default values of java fields. I'm not sure this is the best source to learn from. You may find some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview#t=201707051614391693814 This does not yet include custom editable cells however...